# Action URL changing based on ActionCode settings when sending passwordless login email

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I have 2 frontend interfaces for my firebase project (both housed in the same firebase app in the backend). One is web and one is for iOS.

I'm trying to create passwordless sign-in functionality for the iOS app and have gone through all setup guides regarding setting up dynamic links, custom domains etc.

I have gotten to the point where both the web and iOS apps can both send the email successfully, however the root domain changes between the emails sent from each platform. An example is below:

**Web App:** Sends login email via `firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail` and the resulting root domain in the email is `https://app.domainname.com` (this is correct and is what is set up as a whitelisted domain/dynamic link domain in firebase)

**iOS App:** Using the same function, the resulting root domain is `https://domainname.com` (incorrect). This results in the link going to the non-firebase, generic website and breaking the flow.

If I add the `app` subdomain back to the link generated by the iOS email, the dynamic link does then work, so the issue seems to be isolated to this root domain change specifically.

Upon further investigation, the issue seems to be related to the action code settings.

When the `iOS.bundleId` property is set, or `handleCodeInApp` is `true`, the incorrect root domain is used. This is true for either the web app or the iOS app.

I have done a project find on `domainname.com` in both projects (my iOS app is an ejected expo app so the search included Xcode files for this one) and can't find any instance of the subdomain being missing in either codebase (or the backend codebase for that matter) and am therefore at a loss.

I've looked throughout my firebase settings and can't find any instance of the incorrect one appearing, but am unaware of a search functionality on the platform to be certain. The Action URL (%LINK%) setting in Authentication->Templates appears to be the correct URL.

I am hoping to get to the point where irrespective of the action code settings, the same, correct root domain is used. I assume this is a configuration issue but am at a total loss about how to resolve it, so any help would be appreciated.

For reference, the action code settings in use are below:

```
    var actionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'https://app.domainname.com',
      iOS: {
        bundleId: 'com.domainname.app'
      },
      handleCodeInApp: true
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details on the full email link sent? You can redact sensitive values in the link. If you are setting the same ActionCodeSettings in web and iOS, they should send the same link. Also can you add your iOS app ActionCodeSettings snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone finds this in the future, it turned out for me that the issue was due to a combination of an undocumented lack of support for custom domains in dynamic links in `react-native-firebase`, alongside the fact that the library will only send the email links using the first selected domain in your Firebase Dynamic Links settings.

At the time of writing, the solution was to simply delete all other domains from my Dynamic Links settings, leaving only `PROJECTNAME.page.link`, so that this was the one that got used by the library. From there everything worked as expected.